# How to create or draw routes on maps for my application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am planning to draw routes for different Buses in a ciy on a map. Once i draw those routes i just want to show the user the routes for example from point a to point b for Bus 1 etc.

Since this is a web based mobile app I am planning to use (HTML5,Javascript,jQuery,Ajax)

Any help/tutorial on how to create or draw a map will be of great help. I personally don't have any experience drawing or using maps api.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps JavaScript API is the way to go:

Start here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Then, specifically about paths:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polyline_add